# vue js scoped slots styles error with vue styled components

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, styled-components

I tried using [vue-styled-compoenents](https://github.com/styled-components/vue-styled-components) to style a simple button with some text inside but the styles dont work and I get a scopedSlots issue in the parent component.

This is the code for the button and the text components in `component.js`

```
import styled from 'vue-styled-components';

export const sLabel = styled.label`

  color: #000;
`;

export const sButton = styled.div`

  height: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  background-color: #000;

  ${sLabel} {
    color: #fff;
  }
`;
```

This is my code in my page.

```
<template>

  <sButton>
    <sLabel>Button</sLabel>
  </sButton>

</template>

<script>

import { sButton, sLabel } from './component.js'

export default {
  components: {
    sButton,
    sLabel
  }
}

</script>
```

This is the result I get under the `sButton` styles and nothing under `sLabel`

```
), scopedSlots: this.$scopedSlots
```

But Instead if I just use this code it works.

```
export const sButton = styled.div`

  height: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  background-color: #000;

  label {
    color: #fff;
  }
`;
```

The styles are applied to the parent component if I declare the parent component before the child even if the styles are under the child.

```
export const sButton = styled.div`

  height: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  background-color: #000;

  ${sLabel} {
    color: #fff;
  }
`;

export const sLabel = styled.label`

  color: #000;
`;
```

Can someone tell me where my code is incorrect and what is causing these issues ?